# Privacy issues in Hyperleger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

If a user submit different transactions, is possible to link the different transaction one to each other?
From a privacy point of view, the user is visible on the channel so, potentially may be possible to have a privacy leakage or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is- it depends.

If the user uses the regular, standard x509 based identities then yes - it is easy to link the transactions.

However - if the user uses [identity mixer](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/idemix.html), then it is impossible to link its transactions, because it signs as a random pseudonym each time.